# How to solve error in ExecuteNonQuery() in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf; Integrated Security = True";
con.Open();

// insert command 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO firsttb VALUES ( @n , @p ) ";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n",TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", TextBox2.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Comment: When using `INSERT INTO <table> VALUES` you have to provide all the columns with data. alternatively if inserting into specific table columns then you need to state which columns to insert the data.  `INSERT INTO <table>(columnName1, columnName2,...etc) VALUES (value1, value2,...etc)`

Comment: id is also there but primary key and i have just 2 text box one for name and another password so what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

mention the column names explicitly like below; assuming the column names are `n` and `p`. Also, use an overload of `Add()` method rather `AddWithValue()`

```
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO firsttb(n, p) VALUES ( @n , @p )";
```

Comment: id is also there but primary key and i have just 2 text box one for name and another password so what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the number of columns in firsttb table . It should match with a number of values you are passing through ado.net code.

   E.g If your firsttb table has three column then pass three values in Insert Into statement.
2. Also, check the order of values you are passing. As you are not mentioning column name in Insert Into Statement. Hence order of values you are passing is of high importance.

Try this: as your table has 3 columns and you are passing two values only, In this case, make your Id column as Identity column so that every time you will insert a new record new id will get auto generated and you don't have to modify the code.

```
// Identity Column
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Password varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: id is also there but primary key and i have just 2 text box one for name and another password so what should i do

Comment: id is primary key only or Identity column also?

Comment: If your primary key column is not Identity Column then you have to pass its value as well .. means three value in total

Comment: in form just name and password while in database 3 of them is defined

Comment: in form also you need to pass three values. If you dont have id then you have to create new id every time you insert the record in db

Comment: for id you have to check if there are no records in table then you can use Id = 1 and next time after inserting new record chek if table has any record then fetch the id of the record and add +1 in it so as to have the new id

Comment: @ Muhammad Haris.. If this solves your problem please accept it as answer

Comment: how to make identity column